# Bounty question - solved in comments, but still weak question/solution

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, bounty, comment-replies

Following is a question that I believe was of acceptable quality (albeit a bit specific and lacking some detail), and which was also set up with a bounty. Because I felt it wasn't "answer-worthy", I offered a suggestion to just double check file paths and ultimately that ended up being the solution. My suggestion was upvoted and the problem was solved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397996/html5-audio-tag-not-play-on-iis

Unfortunately, that leaves the question unanswered, and even looking at the question, there's not enough information to even clearly dictate that the file path was a problem. It was simply a "did you remember to plug it in?" comment on my part.

That said, what happens to the bounty? I realize the OP can manually award it, but is that proper protocol given there is no actual answer? Should I re-post my comment as an answer, despite the fact that it wouldn't be a high-quality answer? Should the question be deleted, and if so, does the bounty just disappear? Full transparency here: I would love to receive it. :)

I looked through similar topics here on meta but couldn't find one related to a question that offered a bounty, so forgive me if this seems like a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can edit the question into one that *does* make the question answerable, in the light of the responses to your clarifying questions, then go ahead and do so and feel free to answer the question, once it becomes answerable.  If you don't see any way of making the question answerable, flag the post for moderator attention and ask them to close the question (only a mod can close a bountied question) explaining specifically why the question needs to be closed.

Comment: THe bounty ends in 12 hours, no moderator will remove it.

Comment: @Deduplicator Then could remove it *without* refunding it.